# Intent.ACTION_CALL calls phone but doesn't open call screen

Tags: android, phone-call

I'm using this line to call a number:

```
    context.startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse("tel:" + number)));
```

The problem is that randomly the call is creen isn't opened. With that I mean that the phone is called in the background, but the user is kept on my application.

Anybody experienced a similar issue? How can I make sure the call screen is opened?

Comment: Try `Intent.Action_DIAL` instead of `Intent.Action_CALL`.

Comment: Hi @KartikKaushik I need the phone to be called directly, I don't want the users to have to press call.

Comment: May be you are starting this activity again after this statement by mistake. Like in `onPause()` or something. Can you post the complete code in this class?